Open Ports for SQL Server 2022 Installation
When installing SQL Server 2022, I get a warning message saying "make sure the appropriate ports are open."

I read the Microsoft documentation then created a PowerShell script to open the ports:
# Enable SQL Server ports.
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "SQL Server Default Instance"
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1434 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "Named Instances with Default Port"
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1434 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "SQL Server Browser Service"
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 4022 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "Service Broker"
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 135 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "Transact-SQL Debugger"

# Enable SQL Server Analysis ports.
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 2383 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "SQL Server Analysis Services"
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 2382 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "SQL Server Browser Service"

#Enabling Misc. Applications
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1434 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public -DisplayName "SQL Server Browser Service"

However, I'm still getting the same warning message.
What else do I need to do in order to not get this warning?

I'm not sure that the warning is actually inspecting the firewall rules, but merely warning you that the firewall is enabled and that you need to configure it appropriately for SQL Server. Have attempted to complete the install?

@joeqwerty I disabled Windows Firewall then attempted the install again. This time, the warning was gone! Thanks for your help.
